# Giving gifts to non-Jews at Christmastime

Tags: halacha, gentiles, children-parenting, gifts, non-jewish-holidays

Is it okay at Christmastime to give a gift to a boss or for kids to give gifts to teachers if they are not Jewish?

Comment: Your question text asks about any gift. Your title mentions Christmas gifts. Which do you mean?

Comment: Any religion, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry: I'm still confused. Your title still says "Christmas gifts". Your question still just says "gift". And now your comment says "any religion". I have no idea what you're asking about. Just gifts for Christmas? Gifts for any non-Jewish religious holiday? Gifts for any religious holiday (including Jewish ones)? Gifts for any or no occasion (e.g. birthdays)?

Comment: @msh210 gifts at this season.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited it into the question: tweak _ad lib_. In the future, you can edit your questions yourself to clarify them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not so sure it's as straightforward as follick said. True that Christianity is avodah zarah for us Jews; true also that it is, according to some posekim, also the same for non-Jews. Nevertheless, one of the major leniencies in this regard (alluded to by Shalom in [his answer to the related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12219/37)) is that most non-Jews nowadays aren't אדוק באמונתם, so "frum" that, say, receiving a gift before their holiday will make them run to church to thank their deity.

There still is the issue of chukos hagoyim (imitating non-Jewish practices), though.

On a practical level: maybe indeed it's too late for this year to do anything about it, but how about if you give them an end-of-year present (or whatever you want to call it) far enough in advance - say anytime before Thanksgiving - so that it doesn't have a direct connection to Christmas, but still shows your regard for them?

---

I found something else that bears on this. The Rema ([Yoreh De'ah 148:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&pgnum=144)), citing Terumas Hadeshen, says:

> וכן אם שולח דורון לעובד כוכבים בזמן הזה ביום שיש להם סימן אם יגיע להם דורון בחג ההוא אם אפשר ישלח לו מבערב ואם לא ישלח לו בחג עצמו.
>
> "Similarly, if one is sending a gift to a non-Jew in our times [by which, I guess, he means to distinguish them from the idol-worshippers of old], on the day on which they consider it significant to receive presents on that holiday: if possible, [the Jew] should send him the gift the evening before. If not, he may send it on the holiday itself."

(As Shach there :13 points out, delaying giving the gift until after the holiday would lead to איבה, the non-Jew resenting the Jew for having ignored the occasion. "Especially nowadays," he says, "when it is uncommon for them to go and thank [their deity, for the gift].")

However, in uncensored editions of Shulchan Aruch (such as [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45233&pgnum=118)), the reference is explicated as being to "ביום ח' שאחר ניט"ל שקורין ני"א יאר" - "the eighth day after Christmas, which they call 'New Year.'" Which would mean that giving a non-Jew a gift on Christmas itself might still be problematic either as supporting idolatry or as chukos hagoyim, but if you give it as a New Year's gift, there'd be more room for leniency. (Why the posekim aren't as concerned about the chukos hagoyim angle regarding New Year's, I don't know.)

Though I suppose that it might be argued that conditions were different then - when the non-Jews' resentment could lead to real physical danger to the individual and to the Jewish community generally - than now.

Comment: or maybe give it after the new year as a new year's gift?

Comment: @morahhochman, I guess that might work too (CYLOR, of course, about that - and, for that matter, about my first proposal). The practical problem that I see with that, though, is that by that time it might be too late to correct the mistaken impression that you don't care for or respect them (since you'll have let their holiday season pass without giving them anything).

Comment: regarding "far enough in advance"... there seems to be no such thing in America today.  Christmas advertisements seemed to have started before Halloween from what I heard. :P

Comment: Also, what if the Boss or teacher, is that "frum" that they would praise Jesus on the spot for the gift?

Comment: @avi, on "frum" teachers/bosses, you must be talking about a different class of gifts than I'm used to. :-)

Comment: Alex, what about the _mat'nas chinam_ issue (especially if Christianity is _avoda zara_)?

Comment: @msh: that applies only if you don't know the person (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 151:11). I guess the idea is that if you know them, it's not really *chinam* (maybe because you expect him to eventually reciprocate somehow).

Answer (score 2):

No (Avodah Zara 2a) 
If Christianity is considered Avodah Zarah then it is clearly assur. I know that not everyone holds that it is but in cases of doubt about such a serious issur D'Orisah as Avodah Zarah we need to be machmir.

Comment: @folick So please tell me what we should do, as it is the socially acceptable, and almost a necessity  to give presents to teachers and bosses. (I know this is not a halachic part of the answer, but suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @morahhochman Do you not find it somewhat below our dignity as Jews to give presents to those who have authority over us at this time? One option could be: a letter of appreciation at the end of the civil year.

Comment: @morahhochman In my 10 years of working in the united states, I never bought my boss a gift.   I was forced to participate in a "secret santa" a couple times, but never to give a gift to my boss. Also, I never gave a gift to a teacher for christmas. Only on teacher appreciation day.

Comment: I've been told that there can be pretty strong social pressure in public schools for kids to give small gifts to their teachers.

Comment: Christianity is idolatry (Yad HaHazaka, Maachalot Asurot 11:7)

Comment: @H'Gabriel, if giving a gift to somebody in December (in clear imitation of the surrounding culture) is participating in Christianity, then I agree.  I can't tell if that's the case, though.  Is there any set of measures one can take to give a gift at this time of year without it being a "Christmas gift"?

Comment: I don't really think that it's possible. It may be, but I can't think of any sufficient ways.

Comment: I think it's easy to make a gift not a chrismas gift. Wrap it in Kwanza or Chanukah wrapping, without any hint to winter images, green or red. And if you can, give it after December 26th

Comment: @H'Gabriel, the precise status of Christianity is a long-standing [disagreement](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134/2).

Comment: I understand, that is why am I bringing this opinion.

Comment: @H'Gabriel, year-end bonuses or tips are one example.  I never see my paper carrier but I send him a tip at the end of each secular year because that's the customary time for such things.  Is that a "Christmas gift"?  I sure don't intend it to be.  If it's not, then how does it differ from the gifts mentioned in the question (already assuming they aren't wrapped in Santa paper or the like)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio normally, those tips are called a "Christmas Bonus"

Comment: I think this would go under the category of an action of intention. I think you should make it VERY clear that it is not for Xmas if possible.

Comment: @morahhochman, re "please tell me what we should do": As always, you should not trust this site for practical _halacha_, for which you should consult a competent rabbi.

Comment: @avi A company I worked for referred to them as 'end of year' bonus. Though it's called such, the timing of it being received might still be seen as Xmas?