# Complimenting or giving gifts to gentiles

Tags: halacha, gentiles, gifts, social-convention

My brother recently introduced me to some new Halachot (laws) about not giving gifts to gentiles and not complimenting them. What are the pertinent Halachot that I should be aware of, so that I'll have an idea of which situations I need to be careful about or ask a rabbi about?

Comment: related/duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/giving-gifts-to-non-jews-at-christmastime

Comment: @Michoel but that question is about Xmas not in general.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it was for sure a duplicate (nor did I vote to close it as such), just that it is very much related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kof-k goes through the sugya nicely and provides examples when it would be muter or assur to show favor.

this is link to the sources(I am not going to summarize it because they did that already) http://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108110431W-28%20Lo%20Sichaneim.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In that pdf, there's a reference to Vayikra 7:3 as the part of the Torah that says it is forbidden to show certain favours to goyim. However, when I go to Vayikra 7:3, it only says "And all of its fat he shall offer from it: the tail and the fat covering the innards,". I can't see anything in Rashi's commentary that would lead to that view either. 
Is the author trying to reference something else, or have I misunderstood?