# Jewish protocol towards challah

Tags: gentiles, gifts, challah-shabbat-bread

Can challah be given as a gift to a non-Jew? For instance, if one were to make too much challah Friday morning, would it be acceptable to give a loaf away to a Christian family?

Comment: why not like any other bread.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30192

Comment: Since challah isn't a special kind of bread going back to Sinai it can be treated as any other kind of bread.

Answer (score 1):

(There is theoretical *challah*, i.e. the small portion taken off when making lots of bread which was given to the *kohen* back in the day, that's a different story.)

You mean the traditional braided bread? It's just bread. Yes, you can give it to anyone for any purpose.

There is the custom to eat braided bread on Shabbat, but braided bread is just bread.

Comment: Lo Tichonneim might come into play here. There doesn't seem any reason to be concerned for Eivah here.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes well aware of that; but that would be no different vis-a-vis challah than a boule, peasant bread, pita, or ciabatta. I try to answer the question as asked and intended. Let's assume it's a neighbor and what goes around comes around.