# May I give non-mevushal wine to a non-Jew?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, grapes-wine, lifnei-iver

If I know that non-mevushal wine is available to be used for avodah zarah (as in http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5211.htm)  and that the prohibition against lifnei iver includes non-Jews<sup>[1]</sup>, then am I forbidden to give a non-Jew a bottle of non-mevushal kosher wine as a gift, let alone a bottle of non-kosher wine?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/giving-gifts-to-non-jews-at-christmastime) question and its answers indicates that avodah zarah, according to some, still exists as a problem.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The prohibition of aiding the commission of a transgression is not one that belongs to the family of not harming another. After all, the other in this case is "harming" himself. Rather, by aiding in the commission of a transgression by another, one is to some extent becoming a partner in the sin. This naturally applies whether the other is Jewish or non-Jewish (See R. Elchanan Wasserman, Kovetz Shiurim, Pesachim 95; Responsa Arugat HaBosem YD 235). [Source.](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/pesachim/23pesach.htm)

Answer (score 2):

*Stam yeinam* is not actually *assur* because of an actual concern of biblical *yayin nesech* since we do not actually assume they will use it for *avoda zara*. It's just a *gezeira d'rabanan* to avoid excessive familiarity that would lead to intermarriage and an ultimate abandonment of the *mitzvos*. So *lo sitein michshol* should not apply in your case (of non-mevushal wine).  With regard to giving a gift of wine that already has the status of *stam yeinam* (i.e. regular non-kosher wine), there's a *machlokes achronim* as to whether even deriving indirect benefit (e.g. in gift-giving) is included in the *gezeira* and the *Rama* is *machmir* (Y.D. 123:1; see: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/vayechi.html )

Comment: Adding sources would greatly improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [loewian's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43599/1012), there seems to be no prohibition for a Noahide to consume wine used as libation for idolatry. See Pesahim 73a and Turei Even to Hagigah 13a s.v. ein mosrin, cited by Gilyon ha-Shas Pesahim ibid.

Comment: However, cf. Rabbenu Hananel to Pesahim ibid. who implies that there is a prohibition, as noted by R. Yehuda Gershuni in his Shitah Mekubetzet.

Comment: See also Minhat Hinnukh no. 111 (end of mitzvah) who says that the prohibitions to benefit from idolatry to not apply to Noahides, but see the sources cited in Be-Shulei ha-Minha ibid.