# Seeking a recommendation of a version of Pirkei Avot accessible to a novice

Tags: gentiles, product-recommendation, english, pirke-avot-ethicsof

One of my non-Jewish co-workers has been fascinated with Jewish ethics, and I assume that while searching on the web, he discovered "Ethics of the Fathers". He's read a few adages and has discussed them with me. He's indicated an interest in knowing more about this book.

I'd like to get him a copy of *Pirkei Avot*, in English, of course (it could have Hebrew on a facing page, if "needed"). He needs something "simple" that he can understand as someone unfamiliar with Jewish life or laws.

I think that an explanation that not only accurately translates the Hebrew but also provides some brief historical context to both Pirkei Avot, in general, as well as some bio / history on each Rabbi's saying (so he can get a sense of when the rabbi lived; who he was and what important events may have caused him to state what he did) would be useful.

There are numerous versions of *Pirkei Avot* around, and I am uncertain of which version would be the best option for a "novice". I'd appreciate any recommendation with a short explanation of why you recommend this version over any others.

**Note:** - I'm interested in a physical book form only; not Kindle or just a web resource.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12213 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1583

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks a product recommendation specifically for a non-Jewish audience.

Comment: @SethJ, how is that off topic?

Comment: @Yishai, it has nothing to do with Judaism.

Comment: @sethj, it asks for a recommendation for a book on a Mesechta of Mishnayos.

Comment: @yishai ...for non-Jews.

Comment: @SethJ Please refer to links in msh210's comments and my follow up. If it helps ease your mind, consider the book for my own  use so that I can "debate" the non-Jew. Then, I lend him the book in case he doubts what I say.

Comment: can't comment on quality (preview available on google books) but you can't beat the price http://www.amazon.com/When-Jew-Seeks-Wisdom-Sayings/dp/0874410894/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446228702&sr=1-1&keywords=9780874410891

Comment: @DanF, it's not about easing my mind. It's about the question. I don't believe that, for purposes of this site, recommending products for non-Jews falls under the heading "Judaism", even if the subject matter they seek to learn about (or you seek to teach them) does. If you want a beginner's product, or something like that, that's fine. But if you want a product for non-Jews, I'm sure it exists, but it's not in scope.

Comment: Rav Hirsch's peirush would seem to be a good choice.

Comment: @SethJ if a Jew asked for recommendations for a book to give non-Jewish relatives, or a non-Jew interested in possible (but not certain) conversion asked for recommendations, would you say those are off-topic?

Comment: @Monica, the first, yes, the second, no. This is neither, though it's close to the first. This specifically asks for a book for non-Jews, not a book for beginners or those unaware.

Comment: @SethJ if there were (*chas v'shalom*) an intermarriage in my family, I might reasonably want to educate the gentiles involved in some of our core values.  To me that would be a problem of Jewish life that *I* have, as a Jew, even if a gentile is going to be the beneficiary of the answer.  We don't know why Dan wants to help this person; if motive matters, he can clarify.  If the question had instead been from the coworker -- "I'm not Jewish but I'd like to understand Pirke Avot; what can I read?" -- I think we would answer that; we've answered similar.  Does it matter who's doing the asking?

Comment: @Monica, I think he's intending what you think he's asking, and I think the comments make that point almost painfully obvious. But the question asks for a book for non-Jews. I think an edit might help, but the edit I'm thinking of eliminates the entire motive (or makes it irrelevant).

Comment: @Monica I've edited. Let's see what DanF thinks. DanF, why "of course" and why put quotes around "simple"? Also, I don't think you'll find the contextual information in easily accessible format. You may find PhD theses about some of the rabbis and their adages, though...

Comment: @MonicaCellio (And SethJ, etc.) - You're pretty much correct, i.e. "I'm not Jewish but I'd like to understand Pirke Avot; what can I read?" While not phrased exactly that way, as indicated in my question's detail, he has already indicated an interest in it. I think I've made that quite obvious in my question. I'm not sure what further editing would clarify that point. And, AFAIK, we have had questions indicating that there is nothing wrong with non-Jews knowing about Jewish subjects, as well as opinions within that that states that we can (or perhaps, SHOULD assist, barring specific topics.)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the [Kehot version](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EO-PIRK.DEL#) to meet your criteria of:

> not only accurately translates the Hebrew but also provides some brief historical context to both Pirkei Avot, in general, as well as some bio / history on each Rabbi's saying (so he can get a sense of when the rabbi lived; who he was and what <strike>important events</strike> may have caused him to state what he did) would be useful.

The only thing is, as I remember, important events tend not to be the motivation ascribed to specific sayings. The general timeline from Sinai is introduced as the Mishna unfolds, and as each sage is introduced a short biography is presented. You can get a sample at the link by clicking "View Additional Images".

Although it has Hebrew, it reads in the direction of an English book, so a non-Hebrew speaker will find it more comfortable.

This answer does not constitute an endorsement of purchasing for the recipient intended in the question. For that, CYLOR.