# Christmas and Ex-mas

Tags: words, names, avodah-zarah, christianity, non-jewish-holidays

1. Why do some Jews refer to Christmas as Ex-mas?
2. Is there anything wrong in Jews saying Christmas?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it about Jews -- why other people do or don't say something isn't on-topic here.  I left your "Ex-mas" formulation even though I've *never* heard anybody say that ("Xmas" yes, "Ex-mas" no), because I couldn't tell if it was a typo or if you actually intended to say that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are people who don't like saying "Christ", and therefore don't like saying "Christmas."  If you don't have a strong secular education, you'd assume that "X" just means "fill-in-the-blank", so "X-mas" sounds like a more "kosher" way to refer to the holiday. (This is what my camp counselors did when I was a kid, and that was their explanation.)

As Ze'ev pointed out, however, "X" actually is just a Greek acronym for "Christ", so you gain little there.

The Vilna Gaon is quoted as saying that "Christ" per se is Greek for "anointed", and does not fall under the Talmud's prohibition on saying the name of a pagan deity. Hence I would assume that the same would apply to the term "Christmas."

(Whether you can *wish* someone a happy/merry Christmas is a [different question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34100/5323)...)

Comment: I have heard that some pasken that the X formation is in fact worse as it more points directly to one person, rather than a generic "anointed".

Comment: @Shalom, do you know where the Vilna Gaon says that?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I thought I'd seen it on an Ohr Sameach piece quoting him, though I'm not seeing it on their website now. Would have to look into it.

Comment: @Shalom, please let me know when you find it and send me a link to the source.

Comment: It's not an acronym: just an initial. And however people use it now, it began as a simple scribal abbreviation.

Comment: I have heard the opposite before - that saying "Christ" is worse, because it means (or at least has the connotation of) savior, and is identifying one person as the "savior"

Comment: I hope you don't mind my linkifying that, Shalom. I figured it's easier for both of us than me commenting with a link ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The word *Christ* comes from the Greek Χριστός, and the initial letters, ΧΡ (*chi rho*), was a common abbreviation in handwritten manuscripts and [a symbol for Christianity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Rho).

The English [*Xmas* as an abbreviation of *Christmas* is long-attested](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Xmas): *Xres mæsse* appears in the "Anglo-Saxon Chronicle" (c.1100). At some point in English the *r* was dropped from the abbreviation, and the modern *Xmas* was born. This written abbreviation for *Christmas* can also be said aloud, pronounced as *ex-mas* (though it hardly counts as an abbreviation in this case). [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/xmas) gives two pronunciations: `ˈɛksməs` & `ˈkrɪsməs`.

Comment: I hope the editor gets some of the reputation for significantly improving my answer.

Comment: http://painfulenglish.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/how-to-pronounce-xmas/