# Is the Prohibition on Coveting the Only Thoughtcrime in Torah Law?

Tags: halacha, thought

I read in an answer on this site:

> Halacha doesn't recognize the existence of the Orwell's concept of Thoughtcrime

This makes sense initially because so much of Judaism is based on actions that we do or do not take.  These are usually seen as far more important than our thoughts.

One place where this paradigm breaks down though is in the Ten Commandments themselves.  We are told not to covet our neighbor's property or wife or servants. This seems to be the one major example of thoughtcrime in the Torah. I can also think of no other examples of thoughtcrime in rabbinic laws, although instances may exist.

Is the prohibition on coveting recognized as unique within the framework of halacha, and does anyone write why these ideas are forbidden when other bad thoughts (say daydreaming of murdering someone when it is apparent that you won't actually do it) is not specifically forbidden in the same way?

Comment: The prohibition on coveting is when you act to obtain what you desire. There's a general rule that only actions are punishable, but that doesn't meant you can't sin by thinking. See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/are-thoughts-of-sin-punished-halachically) and [today's Tanya portion](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=12/30/2023).

Comment: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Lo_Tachmod

Comment: Can you post a link to the answer where you found that?

Comment: @MosesSupposes https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34146/31534

Answer (score 3):

Here are some other examples of thoughts that are considered a sin unto themselves.

1. Believing in foreign gods (Sifrei on Bamidbar 15:39).
2. Planning to worship idols (Kiddushin 39b).
3. Sexual fantasies (Avodah Zarah 20b).
4. Rejoicing in an enemy's downfall (Mishlei 24:17).
5. Disdain for our parents and teachers (Yom Kippur Vidui).

There are also certain thought based positive commandments in the Torah, and a person who neglects to think those mandated thoughts, transgresses these commandments.

Here are some examples:

1. The commandment to remember the story of Miriam, the sister of Moshe and Aaron, who was punished for speaking Lashon Hara about Moshe; so that we should not repeat her error [Devarim 24:9; Ramban ad loc.; Ramban, Essin, 7; Chafetz Chaim, Essin, 1).
2. Loving your neighbor as yourself [Vayikra 19:18; Rambam, De'os 10:3; Sefer HaChinuch, 243; Chafetz Chaim, Essin, 2].
3. Judging your fellow favorably [Vayikra 19:15; Rambam, Essin, 147; Chafetz Chaim, Essin, 3].

Please feel free to add to the list...

Comment: Whereas Lo Tachmod seems to not be a thought crime at all

Comment: @RabbiKaii What about לא תתאוה?

Comment: Yep: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.359.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @RabbiKaii Related: When is desiring another man's property permitted https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/when-is-desiring-another-mans-property-permitted?rq=1

Comment: ?מי שלא דן לכף זכות? מקבל לשון הרע

Comment: @MichoelR I added "Judging your fellow favorably".

Comment: @IsraelReader Not "crimes", but there are three mitzvos where the Tur says something you think while you do them is actually part of the mitzvah (as described by the Torah): tzitzis, tefillin, sukkah.

Comment: @IsraelReader Mind you, I'm not actually sure that any of the ones on your second list are actually about "thoughts". I was thinking of making this an independent post question: "remember" Miriam - is that different from "think about Miriam"? "Loving" - that's more like a character trait. "Judging" - I think you're allowed to be choshesh! It's more about how you treat them, and your attitude.

Comment: @MichoelR Did you look up ALL the sources that I cited? Based on your comment, I'm not sure that you did.

Comment: @IsraelReader Of course I didn't. If you have a specific one to point to, which is it?

Comment: @MichoelR It would be courteous to study the sources I refer to, before criticizing what I wrote. ALL the sources are relevant. The Chafetz Chaim (all 3 citations) rules that these are about mandated thoughts, and the commandments are transgressed when a person neglects to think those thoughts at the appropriate times. For example, deep down, a person may know and remember what happened to Miriam, but if they neglect to think about it before they speak Lashon Hara, then that neglect is considered a transgression of the obligation. The same applies to the rest of the list, as the CC explains.

Comment: @IsraelReader I did not mean to be discourteous. But the standard here is to provide links to anything you want the reader to see, and even better to provide clips posted from the money quotes. I don't think it's usual to send the reader off to do extensive research. In any case, I did not criticize, I just mentioned that I believe that the claim that these require thought is not at all obvious (though the Chofetz Chaim does assume it). One would have imagined that these commandments are about something else.